# Splitting groups of CSV ROW's into separate CSV's OR Variables

Tags: arrays, powershell, grouping

```
$groups = Get-Content c:\devices.csv | Group {$_.Substring(0,3)}| %{$_.Group; ""}



    AAAGroup1,192.168.1.1
    AAAGroup1,192.168.1.2

    BBBGroup2,192.168.2.1
    BBBGroup2,192.168.2.2

    CCCGroup3,192.168.3.1
    CCCGroup3,192.168.3.2
```

I have searched far and wide and can only find solutions based on column selections **To output the above data to either a separate variable per group or separate CSV file.** Technically, there's a space in between each group in terms of a spare row, that's it as far as i can see.

```
$groups = Get-Content c:\devices.csv | Group {$_.Substring(0,3)}| %{$_.Group; ""}

ForEach ($Group in $Groups)...
```

Comment: Why are you using `Get-Content`?  Use `Import-Csv`

Comment: Then use substring on the property values instead of on the object!!!

Comment: @EBGreen thanks dude

Comment: This is not really any help though, just saying use a different command to import the data

Comment: Your last (deleted) question asked for the gap and had spaces between columns. And thank's for providing a starting line, ups - you should have written that. You are member long enaugh to know that you can't expect more effort from others than you are willing to invest.

Comment: @LotPings I’m genuinely stuck so, happy to go back to my book and try and work it out if nobody can help me here. Also happy to help others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provided you have a file devices.csv with headers `Device,IPv4`

The following script will add a `calculated property` named `Group` you can use to sort, output to a table and `-GroupBy` or whatever.

```
## Q:\Test\2018\07\10\SO_51267179.ps1

$data = Import-Csv '.\devices.csv' | 
  Select-Object Device,IPv4,@{n='Group';e={$_.Device.Substring(0,3)}}

$data | Format-Table -GroupBy Group
```

Sample output

```
   Group: AAA

Device    IPv4        Group
------    ----        -----
AAAGroup1 192.168.1.1 AAA
AAAGroup1 192.168.1.2 AAA

...snip...
```

To output each group to it's own .csv

```
$data = Import-Csv '.\devices.csv' | 
  | Group-Object {$_.Device.Substring(0,3)}| ForEach-Object {
    $_.Group | Export-Csv "$($_.Name).csv" -NoTypeInformation
}
```

Sample output:

```
> gc .\AAA.csv
"Device","IPv4"
"AAAGroup1","192.168.1.1"
"AAAGroup1","192.168.1.2"
```

Comment: Nice one - Do you not get a "Missing '=' operator after key in hash literal." Error after calling the data variable to pipe to FT?

Comment: A terminating `}` got lost on copy and paste, Fixed.

Comment: Thanks for this. One last question, how could i take this output but generate a csv per group?

Comment: $data | Select-Object Group | Export-Csv C:\$group.csv < It's definitely not this

Comment: See changed answer,

Comment: Do you know why each line has " " between the values, Can this not be removed?

Comment: It's the default output format of Export-Csv and can't be changed AFAIK - only the delimiter. While the double quotes increase the file size,even if not necessary to allow delimiters to appear inside a field, most applications will accept them. See [csv on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values)